# How to get Designer Support for VisualStateGroups in Windows 8.1 XAML Apps

Tags: .net, vb.net, winrt-xaml, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-designer

There used to be really great designer support for Windows 8.0 apps in Visual Studio 2012.  In the [Device Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj129464.aspx), you could move to different `VisualStates` within the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` on your page and it would update the appropriate properties at design time.

In 8.1, the `VisualState`s are [no longer based on specific snapped layouts](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/07/02/build-talk-of-the-week-beautiful-apps-at-any-size-on-any-screen.aspx), but you can still use the `VisualStateManager` and update based on the screen `width`.

*Q*: How can I get these changes to update at design time?

---

Here's a simple example of a change that works at runtime, but not design time.

**MainView.xaml.vb**:

```vb
Private Sub MainView_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    AddHandler Me.SizeChanged, AddressOf WindowSizeChanged
    ApplyViewState(Me.Width, Me.Height)
End Sub

Private Sub WindowSizeChanged(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs)
    ApplyViewState(e.NewSize.Width, e.NewSize.Height)
End Sub

Private Sub ApplyViewState(ByVal viewWidth As Double, ByVal viewHeight As Double)
    If viewWidth < 350 Then
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(Me, "SmallLayout", True)
    Else
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(Me, "RegularLayout", True)
    End If
End Sub
```

**MainView.xaml**:

```xaml
<Page x:Name="PageRoot"
    x:Class="WinStoreMvvmTemplate.View.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    
    <Grid Background="Red" x:Name="ContentGrid">
        
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="RegularLayout"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="SmallLayout">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ContentGrid"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

---

Here's a view at **Design Time**: *(incorrect)*

[image: design]

Here's a view at **Run Time**: *(correct)*

[image: runtime]